# Adding space between comma and dots

Tags: spacing, punctuation

In general, we should put a space after a comma, like `$x,\,y$` instead of `$x,y$`. However, I am not sure how to handle the case with `\dots`. Is it necessary to write `$1,\,\dots,\,,\,n$`, or just `$1,\dots,n$` for convenience? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure about the first statement. If you are listing two separate variables, use `$x$,~$y$` (the tie will ensure no line break); if you're writing `$x,y\in X$`, then I don't see reasons for an additional space.

Comment: You claim, "In general, we should put a space after a comma". Well `,` has status `math-punct`, and TeX automatically inserts some whitespace after characters with status `math-punct`. Are you maybe arguing that TeX should insert *more whitespace* than it already does?

Comment: @Mico I don't know the automatical space after comma, because I had tested and found the space in ```$x$, $y$``` wider than that in ```$x,y$```.

Comment: @FranzNietzsche - Just for the record: I did *not* claim in my comment that the whitespace in `$x$, $y$` is the same as that in `$x,y$`. Do please compare `$x,y$` with `$x\mathord{,}y$`, though. (Aside: TeX does not insert whitespace around objects with status `math-ord`.

Comment: @Mico I see, so ```,``` in math mode indeed inserts space, but shorter than ```\,```, and there is no need to add space by myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all standard implementations of the PlainTeX and LaTeX formats, the character `,` ("comma") has status `math-punct` (for "math punctuation") when used in math mode.

TeX inserts a bit whitespace after (but not before) objects of type math-punct. To override this setting, one can write `\mathord{,}` or, more succinctly, just `{,}`.

Syntactically speaking, there is a *significant difference* between `$0,1,2,3,\dots,n$` on the one hand and `$0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, \dots, $n$`. In the former case, the subject in an arithmetic sequence; in the latter, it's just a collection of numbers (here: from 0 to n) that needn't share any common formal structure. As the following screenshot demonstrates, `$0,1,2,3,\ldots,n$` and `$0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, \ldots, $n$` are not typeset the same way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$0{,}9$ % no whitespace

$0,9$

$0{,}1{,}2{,}3{,}\ldots{,}n$ % no whitespace -- too tight

$0,1,2,3,\ldots,n$ % Typeseting a seqence

$0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, \ldots, $n$ % note: the commas are not in math mode
\end{document}
```